# How to keep a changing view centered?

Tags: swift, uiview, swift5

I am creating a UIView that is basically a transparent UIView with a border.

This view is being animated using this code

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
  var frame = areaScanRect.frame
  frame.size.width = frame.size.width * 0.8
  frame.size.height = frame.size.height * 1.2

  areaScanRect.frame = frame
}, completion: nil)
```

The view has its frame like (0,0,200,100).

I need this view to be centered on the main view.

If I simply add the rectangle to the main view, it appears at (0,0), not at the screen center obviously.

Then I add constraints, to make it center.

```
areaScanRect.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  areaScanRect.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
  areaScanRect.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
  areaScanRect.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: areaScanRect.bounds.size.width),
  areaScanRect.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: areaScanRect.bounds.size.height)
])
```

`areaScanRect` shows at the correct position but as the animation goes, is not being centered.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this code will work:
'''

```
    func setMyView(_point: CGPoint) {
    
    var newView = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * point.x, y: bounds.size.height * point.y)
    
    var oldView = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width * layer.anchorPoint.x, y:      bounds.size.height * layer.anchorPoint.y);

   
    newView = newView.applying(transform)
      
    oldView = oldView.applying(transform)


     var position = layer.position


     position.x -= oldView.x

     position.x += newView.x


     position.y -= oldView.y

     position.y += newView.y


     layer.position = position

   layer.anchorView = point

     }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```swift
myView.center.x = view.center.x
myView.center.y = view.center.y
```

It will centre your view.

However I'd suggest only placing your view inside the view setting its Y and X coordinates instead of using constraints

Comment: Not working for me. View is not centered, Sorry.

Comment: Try without the constraints